# Use Java variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I am currently facing issues with using a java variable (set from a database record) in JavaScript for the datePicker UI. I want to set the java variable to the var unavailable in javascript so that the dates which has already been booked with be unclickable.

I know that javascript is on the client side and java is on the server side which is will I can't figure out. I've looked up JSON, XML as ways of transporting the data by it's very hard to understand and implement into my situation.

**SQL**

```html
drop table if exists appointment_booked;
drop table if exists doctor_unavailability;
drop table if exists doctor;


CREATE TABLE DOCTOR
(dc_id int,
dc_name CHAR (20),
CONSTRAINT PK_DOCTOR PRIMARY KEY (dc_id));

CREATE table doctor_unavailability
(dc_id int,
avail_day VARCHAR (15),
CONSTRAint fk_doctor_availability FOREIGN KEY (dc_id) REFERENCES DOCTOR (dc_id));

CREATE TABLE appointment_booked
(dc_id int,
patient_id int,
bookedDate VARCHAR (10),
CONSTRAINT PK_appointment_booked PRIMARY KEY (dc_id,patient_id));

insert into doctor
values(12345, "John Smith");

insert into doctor
values(98765, "Mary Kelly");

insert into doctor_unavailability
values(12345, "02/25/2016");

insert into doctor_unavailability
values(12345, "02/26/2016");

insert into doctor_unavailability
values(98765, "02/28/2016");

insert into doctor_unavailability
values(98765, "02/29/2016");

insert into appointment_booked
values(12345, 9876, "02/20/2016");

insert into appointment_booked
values(12345, 6543, "02/21/2016");
```

**Doctor.java**

```js
package validate;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Doctor {

 public int dc_id = 12345;
 public String dc_name = "John Smith";
 public int patient_id = 1469;
 public String avail_day = null;
 public String bookedDate = null;
 boolean found = false;

 public boolean isFound() {
  return found;
 }

 public String getBookedDate() {
  return bookedDate;
 }

 public void setBookedDate(String bookedDate) {
  this.bookedDate = bookedDate;
 }

 public int getpatient_id() {
  return patient_id;
 }

 public void setpatient_id(int patient_id) {
  this.patient_id = patient_id;
 }

 public int getDc_id() {
  return dc_id;
 }

 public void setDc_id(int dc_id) {
  this.dc_id = dc_id;
 }

 public String getDc_name() {
  return dc_name;
 }

 public void setDc_name(String dc_name) {
  this.dc_name = dc_name;
 }

 public String getAvail_day() {
  return avail_day;
 }

 public void setAvail_day(String avail_day) {
  this.avail_day = avail_day;
 }

 public void book(String url) {
  //
  // database work
  //
  try {
   // open a connection
   Connection con = null;
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking", "user", "user");
   // create the sql command
   PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO appointment_booked VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
   prep.setInt(1, dc_id);
   prep.setInt(2, patient_id);
   prep.setString(3, bookedDate);
   prep.executeUpdate();

  } catch (Exception sqlex) {
   found = false;
   System.out.println("Error here");
   System.out.println(sqlex);
  }

  System.out.println("date: " + bookedDate);
  System.out.println(patient_id);

 }

 /*
  * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */
   public void datesBooked(String url)
    {
    //    
    // database work
    //               
         try{
          // open a connection
           Connection con = null;
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking", "user", "user");
       // create the sql command
           PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("Select * from Student where dc_id=?");  
           prep.setInt(1,dc_id);
         
           ResultSet rs  = prep.executeQuery();
           if(rs.next())
           {
            dc_id = rs.getInt(1);
            patient_id = rs.getInt(2);
            bookedDate = rs.getString(3);
            
         
            
           }
           else
             
           prep.close();
           con.close();
           
          }
         catch(Exception sqlex)
         {
           
           System.out.println(sqlex);
         }  
         System.out.println(dc_id);
      System.out.println(patient_id);
      System.out.println(bookedDate);
   
    }
 
 
 
}
```

**Index.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
 type="text/css" media="all" />
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 var unavailableDates = [ "", "" ];

 function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
    + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
   return [ true, "" ];
  } else {
   return [ false, "", "Unavailable" ];
  }
 }

 $(function() {
  $('#bookedDate').datepicker({
   beforeShowDay : unavailable,
  })
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="validator.jsp">
  Choose your date: <input type="text" id="bookedDate" name="bookedDate"
   required /> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Validator.jsp**

```html
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page errorPage="errorPage.jsp"%>
<jsp:useBean id="doctor" class="validate.Doctor" scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="doctor" property="*" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <%
          session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1800);  // 30 minute time out 
          doctor.book("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ebooking;user;user");
          response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
         
        %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: populate those details from java in jsp . and use javascript to access that field by DOM forms  access.

Comment: @Jimmy Are there any well-explained examples? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options for accessing that variable:

(1) [Utilize a JavaBean](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm)

1. Make sure your bean implements java.io.Serializable
2. Make sure your bean has a zero-arg constructor
3. Make sure your bean has public getter and setter methods
4. Add a useBean action in your JSP

   ```
   <jsp:useBean id="myBean" class="com.package.YourBeanClass"/>
   ```
5. Access Bean Variables in your JSP (from JavaScript or HTML)

   ```
   <p> This is the variable from my Bean: <%=myBean.getProperty()%> </p>
   ```

(2) If you have access to a Session, you can set the variable in the Session of your Java application and access it in your JSP

1. Set the attribute in your Session

   ```
   mySession.setAttribute("myVariable", theVariable);
   ```
2. Access the session attribute in your JSP

   ```
   <p> This is the variable from the Session: <%=session.getAttribute("myVariable")%> </p>
   ```